# how to set data in textbox after sax parsing

Tags: android, textbox, sax

i  parse the xml file and all data will parsed but i dont understand how to set this data in textview ? give me some idea about that

```
    public class GtuItemXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    Gtudownload gtudownload;
    Questionpaper questionpaper;

    // Show me the XML.
    private String currentString = "";
    private String charactersString = "";
    private Branch branch;
    private Year year;
    private Semester semester;
    private int branchCount = 0;
    private int yearCount = 0;
    private int semesterCount = 0;

//  private ArrayList<Gtudownload> itemsList = new ArrayList<Gtudownload>();
//  
//  public ArrayList<Gtudownload> getItemsList() {
//      return itemsList;
//  }

    public Gtudownload getGtudownload(){
        return this.gtudownload;
    }
    public Questionpaper getQuestionpaper()
    {
        return this.questionpaper;
    }


    // Called when tag starts
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        Log.i("GTU ", localName);
        if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Gtudownload")) {
            gtudownload = new Gtudownload();
            currentString = "Gtudownload";

        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Questionpaper")) {
            gtudownload.setQuestionpaper(new Questionpaper());
            gtudownload.getQuestionpaper().setBranchList(new ArrayList<Branch>());
            currentString = "Questionpaper";
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Branch")) {
            branch = new Branch();
            gtudownload.getQuestionpaper().getBranchList().add(branch);
            gtudownload.getQuestionpaper().getBranchList().get(branchCount).setYearList(new ArrayList<Year>());
            currentString = "Branch";
            Log.i("Branch", attributes.getValue("value"));
            branch.setValue(attributes.getValue("value"));
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Year")) {
            year = new Year();
            gtudownload.getQuestionpaper().getBranchList().get(branchCount).getYearList().add(year);
            gtudownload.getQuestionpaper().getBranchList().get(branchCount).getYearList().get(yearCount).setSemesterList(new ArrayList<Semester>());
            currentString = "Year";
            Log.i("Year ", attributes.getValue("value"));
            year.setValue(attributes.getValue("value"));
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("semester")) {
            semester = new Semester();          
            currentString = "semester";
            Log.i("Semester ", attributes.getValue("value"));
            semester.setValue(attributes.getValue("value"));
            gtudownload.getQuestionpaper().getBranchList().get(branchCount).getYearList().get(yearCount).getSemesterList().add(semester);
        } else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("url")){ 
            currentString = "url";
        }

    }

    // Called when tag closing
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Questionpaper")){
            branchCount=0;           
        }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Branch")){
            yearCount = 0;
            branchCount++;
        }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("Year")){
            semesterCount = 0;
            yearCount++; 
        }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("semester")){
            semesterCount++;
        }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("url")){
            gtudownload.getQuestionpaper().getBranchList().get(branchCount).getYearList().get(yearCount).getSemesterList().get(semesterCount).setUrl(charactersString);
            Log.i("URL", charactersString);
        }
        currentString = "";
        charactersString= "";

    }

    // Called to get tag characters
    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
            throws SAXException {
        charactersString = new String(ch, start, length);
        charactersString = charactersString.trim();
    }

}
```

this is my activity and how can i set this parsing data in into textview

```
    public class GtudldActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private TextView xmlOutput;
    TextView example[];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        xmlOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.xmlOutput);

        Gtudownload gtudownload = parseXML();

    }

    private Gtudownload parseXML() {

        Gtudownload gtudownload = null;

        try {

            Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", "Start");
            /** Handling XML */
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance(); 
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();       
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader(); 

            GtuItemXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new GtuItemXMLHandler();
            xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
            InputSource is = new InputSource(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.mgtu));


            gtudownload = myXMLHandler.getGtudownload();

            Log.i("Data",gtudownload+"");
            xr.parse(is);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.w("AndroidParseXMLActivity", e);
        }

        //xmlOutput.setText(gtudownload.toString());

        return gtudownload;

    }
}
```

Comment: are you getting value inside your activity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll get so many examples for this on google. I am showing you one of the. Just try [this](http://androidmaterial.blogspot.in/2012/04/xml-parsing-with-sax-parser-in-android.html)

I hope it may help you. If you've any doubt, just post it here

Comment: That's why I am telling you to search on google. You'll definitely find the example which matches to your code. Else post your entire code here